# Way of storing data in the session scope in php and the life cycle

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Is there a way of storing variables in a **PHP** application in the session scope or the application scope...? At the same time can someone please explain the **life cycle** of a php program..? 
Thanx...

Comment: You're second question question about life cycle is broad. However, for the first you can just define constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the application scope you can use the [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) function.
- For the session scope you can use the [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) array.
- For the third question....too too broad.Anyway you can take a look to this [tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/laruence/the-php-life-cycle). Just Google it.

Answer (score 0):

life cycle of a php program is very short.
It's not like a desktop application constantly running in your browser, and not even a demon with persistent connection to your desktop application. It's more like a command line utility - doing it's job and exits. It runs discrete:

1. a browser makes a call
2. PHP wakes up, creates an HTML page, sends it to the browser **and dies**
3. Browser renders that HTML and shows it to the user.
4. User clicks a link
5. a browser makes a call
6. **another PHP instance, knowing nothing of the previous call, wakes up** and so on

That's why you need sessions - to save the variables between calls.